# numeric out of range 1264 out of range value

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-error-1264

I have table X with 2 columns Address ( varchar ) , Date ( int ).
I want to drop column address so that I run this command:

```
alter table x drop column address
```

I get the error message: numeric out of range: 1264  out of range value for column date at row 1.

- I check all values in Date column and they are still ok ( smaller than the maximum length of int type ).
- I try to change type from int to bigint and set all values in date column to null but I still get this error message.
- This issue happends on my UAT server, It works well at my local.
  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Are you saying the error happens when you alter the table?

Comment: Seems unlikely , please add full table definition and full error message.

Comment: Please also provide version of MariaDB/MySQL server

Comment: here is more information:
- Mariadb: 10.2.40
- Table definition: ID (int), date (int), address (varchar 255) . Sorry I cant give you more information
- the error: Error code 1264. Out of range value for column 'date' at row 1. The sql being executed was : alter table x drop column  date
I run this command on mysql workbench. I confirm that it works on my localhost, but I dont understand why this happens on my UAT server

Comment: If it works on local but not UAT then there is a difference between the two environments which I cannot start to guess.

Comment: @P.Salmon you can forget local.  On my UAT , Mariadb: 10.2.40, how can I know what is exactly happening with 1264 error